# How do you symmetrize a 3x3 matrix?

Tags: matrices

Let's say that I have the following matrix: $\begin{bmatrix}
5 &3  &0 \\ 
0 &0  &5 \\ 
7 &3  &1 
\end{bmatrix}$

How do I symmetrize this matrix, so that I get the following?  I am confused about where the original matrix components get moved around to.

$\left (\begin{bmatrix}
5 &3  &0 \\ 
0 &0  &5 \\ 
7 &3  &1 
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
5 &0  &7 \\ 
3 &0  &3 \\ 
0 &5  &1 
\end{bmatrix}  \right ) = \begin{bmatrix}
10 &3  &7 \\ 
3 &0  &8 \\ 
7 &8  &2 
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: That's just adding the transpose of the original matrix to itself.

Answer (score 3):

$$M=\dfrac{M+M^T}{2}+\dfrac{M-M^T}{2}$$
$\dfrac{M+M^T}{2}$is symmetric part

This work is look like ,to rewrite function $f(x)$
as $g(x)+h(x)$

$g(x)$ is even part of $f(x)$

$h(x)$ is odd part of $f(x)$

and $$f(x)=g(x)+h(x)=\dfrac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}+\dfrac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}$$